# Jenkins - How to get exit code of python script?

Tags: python, python-3.x, jenkins

I try to run a python script in a pipeline. It has sys.exit(2) but Jenkins build always has a SUCCESS status.

I've tried to run it from the terminal and `echo $?` returns 2. How can I pass the exit code to Jenkins?

```
node {
    stage('Stage') {
        def result = sh returnStatus: true, script: 'python3 script.py'
        echo "RESULT IS $result"
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have any statement in your script like printing SUCCESS?

Comment: @slashpai No, there are not any explicit references to the build states in the code.

Comment: Looks pretty similar to this one, which has an answer: https://devops.stackexchange.com/questions/885/cleanest-way-to-prematurely-exit-a-jenkins-pipeline-job-as-a-success